# making a named list from vectors without copying/pasting

Tags: r, list, vector, get

I have several vectors to combine into a named list ("my_list"). The names of the vectors are already stored in the vector ("zI").

```
> zI
[1] "Chemokines"            "Cell_Cycle"            "Regulation"           
[4] "Senescence"            "B_cell_Functions"      "T_Cell_Functions"     
[7] "Cell_Functions"        "Adhesion"              "Transporter_Functions"
[10] "Complement"            "Pathogen_Defense"      "Cytokines"            
[13] "Antigen_Processing"    "Leukocyte_Functions"   "TNF_Superfamily"      
[16] "Macrophage_Functions"  "Microglial_Functions"  "Interleukins"         
[19] "Cytotoxicity"          "NK_Cell_Functions"     "TLR"
```

If it's a small number of vectors, I'd simply do

```
my_list <- setNames(list(Chemokines, Adhesion), c("Chemokines", "Adhesion"))
```

I'd like to find a smarter way, other than to combine the vector names into a long string and then copying/pasting.

```
> toString(zI)
[1] "Chemokines, Cell_Cycle, Regulation, Senescence, B_cell_Functions, T_Cell_Functions, Cell_Functions, Adhesion, Transporter_Functions, Complement, Pathogen_Defense, Cytokines, Antigen_Processing, Leukocyte_Functions, TNF_Superfamily, Macrophage_Functions, Microglial_Functions, Interleukins, Cytotoxicity, NK_Cell_Functions, TLR"
> my_lists <- list(Chemokines, Cell_Cycle, Regulation, Senescence, B_cell_Functions, T_Cell_Functions, Cell_Functions, Adhesion, Transporter_Functions, Complement, Pathogen_Defense, Cytokines, Antigen_Processing, Leukocyte_Functions, TNF_Superfamily, Macrophage_Functions, Microglial_Functions, Interleukins, Cytotoxicity, NK_Cell_Functions, TLR)
> my_lists <- setNames(my_lists, zI)
```

This is probably a really fundamental question, but I've searched and read about 10 separate threads and still can't figure it out. Much thanks for any help!

Comment: If you start on a fresh R session with only the objects mentioned in 'my_lists`, then `mget(ls())`

Comment: That's beautiful! Thank you! @akrun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `mget` to get the values of the character strings.

```
mget(zI)
```